# Did Worf consider any race honorable?

Tags: star-trek, worf

I'm currently re-watching Star Trek: The Next Generation, and between that and Deep Space Nine it seems like Worf finds a lot of species dishonorable.  "The Romulans are without honor," "The Cardissians have no honor," I'm sure there are others.

Has Worf ever described any people or any group as "honorable"?  Who?

Comment: After things that happen in TNG and DS9, I think he feels the same about Klingons, probably just considers honor on an individual basis now...  Worf has second place for being in the most Star Trek episodes, and shows tremendous growth during that time, so this answer could be different depending _when_ you're asking about.

Comment: @Izkata, the events of "Sins of the Father" certainly left me disappointed in the Klingons.  I'll rephrase my question.

Comment: Worf considered the Antedeans to be  "a handsome race." Does that count? Of course considering that the two he had seen were revealed to be assassins, probably not.

Comment: On a more serious note, if Worf were to consider any race honorable I would bet it would be the Jem'Hadar. A race of pure warriors meant only to fight and do battle. Especially so after the events of the DSN [By Inferno's Light](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/By_Inferno%27s_Light_(episode)). But as Izkata said, by the end of everything he more than likely judged most races on a person by person basis (although he probably still hated all Romulans).

Comment: Side note about Worf's maturity - as I only [recently realized](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/35082/2242), the character was only 24 years old at the start of TNG, and 35 years old at the end of DS9 (which made him still rather young for a Klingon)

Comment: I'd also agree that Worf's philosophy matures a lot during TNG and DS9. He starts out as a bit of a stereotypical "child trying to regain his cultural heritage". A lot of his "Klingon-ness" early on comes from what he *thinks* he knows about Klingons (having been raised by humans). The more time he spends around actual Klingons, the more nuanced his concepts of honor become.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Worf believes Starfleet and by extension the Federation to be honorable institutions else he would not be a part of them.  Worf believes Klingon society to be honorable, despite his own personal experiences with the Empire.  He would not have resigned from Starfleet to fight in the Klingon civil war if he felt otherwise.

Worf's judgments are mostly cultural, not racial.  Clearly he has a deep hatred of the Romulan Empire for slaughtering his parents at Khitomer.  But Romulans and Cardassians are also deemed to be without honor because their societies do not seem to value personal honor as a central and guiding principal of individual behavior.  Treachery seems much more acceptable to them as a path to success and advancement.  Because of this Worf takes a dim view of all Romulans and Cardassians instead of assuming the ones he's met have been outliers or a few bad actors.  Look around at today's societies and you'll see similar demonization of groups who live by different moral codes, so Worf's uncompromising personal stance is not novel by any means.

Comment: Somehow, [Juror number Ten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve_Angry_Men#Casts) sprung to mind when reading your last sentence. Was that the intention?

Comment: @bitmask: it's a very general cognitive bias: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-group_homogeneity

Comment: I also like the concept in "Yesterday's Enterprise" that the battle of Neranda III where the Enterprise-C defended a Klingon outpost from the Romulans an honorable act. This helped the Klingon peace in the original timeline.