# Did the Rozhenkos speak with an accent?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, accent

Was there a deliberate "foreignness" to the Rozhenkos' speech in ST:TNG?

In-universe, it would make sense: they were NOT native speakers (Belorussians or Russians by ancestry, and lived in Russia/USSR territory once they returned to Earth).

Out of universe, [Sergey Rozhenko](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Sergey_Rozhenko) was played by [Theodore Bikel](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Theodore_Bikel), who Memory Alpha notes as "a master of languages, dialects, and accents, he often plays ethnic roles".

However, I'm looking for specific in-universe confirmation of actual speech of Sergey and Helena being "foreign" - a noticeable accent; or ESL patterns of speech.

Comment: An preferred answer I'd be interested in would be either backed up by audio/video clip; or a quote on the topic from an actor or one of the people involved with the show.

Comment: Sergey and Helena are specifically mentioned as having brought Work up on the planet Gault, but there's no further hard in-universe evidence of the Rozhenkos having any particular accent outside the characterizations by the actors. The accents used in "Family" by Theodore Bikel and Georgia Brown are Russian and are definitely affected (Bikel is Austrian whilst Brown was English). Likewise the name Rozhenko is predominantly found in Russia (http://www.name-list.net/russia/firstname/Rozhenko).

Comment: @Selezen - if you have a clip showing the accents, that's what I'm looking for (I speak Russian so I can easily tell a russian accent, even Sean Connery fake one :)

Comment: @DVK - here's a clip: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ueUVFOmZHg

Comment: With the universal translator, <insert-language>SL speakers probably sound like natives, smoothing over swapped or missing words and correcting grammar.

Comment: @DVK - OK, I didn't really understand your question, I thought maybe you were asking if the accents shown onscreen were "deliberate" or were just a consequence of the actors not trying to hide their natural accents. I'll put it as an answer, but out of curiosity, how were you so familiar with the characters and their background on the show if you'd never seen the episodes where they appeared?

Comment: @Hypnosifl - I've seen, but a while ago. Plus, Memory Alpha :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the two characters were portrayed with accents onscreen. [Here's a clip link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ueUVFOmZHg).

Answer (score 2):

The [original screenplay](https://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/178.txt) clearly identifies them thusly;

> SERGEY & HELENA ROZHENKO MATERIALIZE on the platform. **They are of Russian descent,** and carry themselves with pride and dignity. Sergey is compact, barrel-chested... a retired Starfleet Chief growing old gracefully. His wife is short of stature and yet there is an underlying strength to her which belies her slight appearance.

---

I've identified two videos that show the character actors using their own naturally accented (e.g. not Russian) voices, to demonstrate that they were using a fake accent on the show.

### Georgia Brown:

### Theo Bikel

As you can see, Bikel does have a strong (and highly noticeable) Eastern European accent that carries over into his depiction of Sergey Rozhenko whereas Georgia Brown is an English character actor who is clearly putting on a cod Russian accent.

Comment: "cod russian accent"?

Comment: @DVK - As in unconvincing. Her accent is all over the place veering wildly between what I can only describe as "stage-Russian" and something like Slovenian?

Comment: According to Memory Beta, the colony was settled by the Siberian collective; http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Siberian_Collective

Comment: his accent as both Rozhenko and as Rabbi Koslov (in Bab5, Ep. TKO), is pretty much what I hear from several Ukrainian expatriots weekly at church.